# OnItemClickListener not working with AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview, onitemclicklistener

I used an autoCompleteTextView with customLayout and Adapter, but the issue is when we click on an item in suggestions, neither the item values gets filled in autoCompleteTextView nor the OnItemClickListener get fired.

The code filters the suggestions with the text entered in autoCompleteTextView, but nothing happends onClick Event.

Below is my code

TeamSuggestionAdapter.java file

```
package com.material.ipladmin;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;




public class TeamsSuggestionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Team> implements Filterable {

    private Context context;

    private List<Team> allTeams;

    private List<Team> teams;

    private ListFilter listFilter = new ListFilter();


    public TeamsSuggestionAdapter(Context context, List<Team> teams) {
        super(context, 0, teams);
        this.context = context;
        this.allTeams = teams;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return allTeams.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Team getItem(int i) {
        return allTeams.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        if(view == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.add_match_suggestions_layout, viewGroup, false);
        }

        CircleImageView logo = view.findViewById(R.id.suggestionItemlogoImage);
        TextView name = view.findViewById(R.id.suggestionItemName);
        LinearLayout linearLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.addMatchSuggestionsLinearLayout);

        Team team = getItem(i);

        Glide.with(context).load(team.logo).into(logo);
        name.setText(team.teamName);
        linearLayout.setTag(team.teamId);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return listFilter;
    }


    class ListFilter extends Filter {

        private Object lock = new Object();


        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence prefix) {

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if(teams == null) {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    teams = new ArrayList<>(allTeams);
                }
            }

            if (prefix == null || prefix.length() <= 0) {

                synchronized (lock) {
                    results.values = teams;
                    results.count = teams.size();
                }

            }
            else
            {

                String searchThis = prefix.toString().toLowerCase();

                List<Team> searched = new ArrayList<>();

                for (int i=0; i<teams.size(); i++) {

                    if (teams.get(i).teamName.toLowerCase().contains(searchThis)) {
                        searched.add(teams.get(i));
                    }

                }

                results.values = searched;
                results.count = searched.size();

            }

            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults results) {

            if (results.values != null) {

                allTeams = (ArrayList<Team>) results.values;

            } else {

                allTeams = null;

            }

            if (results.count > 0 ) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
            return ((Team) resultValue).teamId;
        }
    }

}
```

add_match_suggestions_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:id="@+id/addMatchSuggestionsLinearLayout">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/suggestionItemlogoImage"
        android:src="@drawable/default_team_logo"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/suggestionItemName"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:text="Suggestion Item name"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
TeamsSuggestionAdapter TeamsAdapter = new TeamsSuggestionAdapter(this, teams);

        autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(TeamsAdapter);

        autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                Toast.makeText(AddMatchActivity.this, "Item Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to my LinearLayout in `add_match_suggestions_layout.xml` and removed `focusable` & `clickable` from it, solved the problem.

Comment: Have you ever figured out why? I wish they put this on the documentation... (or I wish it was easier to find this type of info on the documentation)